# Ubuntu 15.10 in VirtualBox reboot

Tags: virtualbox

I am a beginner interested in learning about Linux and thus intend to install Ubuntu in VirtualBox.

I have followed the instructions as stated in this website:
http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-on-VirtualBox

I am currently using Lenovo Yoga 3.

The error I am facing is after the installation phase after clicking on "Restart Now".

When I login after restarting, the screen does not proceed further on and just displays a background as shown.[Ubuntu Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl7E7.png)

Is there any possible mistakes I have made during the installation phase and how should I proceed to be able to use Ubuntu like anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Virtualbox.
2. Select your virtual OS.
3. Click on `Settings`.

   [image: 1]
4. Goto `Storage`, right-click on whatever attachment is there under `Controller: IDE` and remove it.

   [image: 2]
5. Restart Virtualbox.

Comment: Hi, I have followed the procedure you have suggested for me.

However, I am still unable to solve the problem. 
I am still facing the same problem after logging in to Ubuntu and am still stuck at the same screen as shown in my question.

Is there anything else that can be done?